# format a String by a notation

Tags: java, slf4j, apache-commons

I have a string such as following:
`Filed Id is invalid, value = {} and valid ranges = '{},{},{}'`
and I want replace `{}` by custom value in runtime.
I see this pattern in `SLF4J` and real question is : Is there a third party utility for support this requirement instead of using `String.replace`?

Comment: java.text.MessageFormat, String.format().

Comment: string format does what you want `String myString = "Hello %s";` and `String.format(myString,"[NAME]");` or just `String.format("Hello %s","[NAME]");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by *JB Nizet*, [java.text.MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) can do it, as well as String.format()

SLF4J uses [org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/helpers/MessageFormatter.html) so I guess you can use it, too.

I personally find [org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) very convenient and powerful if you need some advanced formatting. For example, you can pass a Map of named values (key-value) as an argument, or implement your own lookup (I did it to ensure that each placeholder receives a value). You can also specify how replacement variables are formatted ({varible}, __variable__, #variable#, or %{variable}), and more. Having said that, you must explicitly name massage variables in order to use it.